# How do I gain access to the info inside a PFObject?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I am importing the objects from parse, but I need to gain access to the information inside. The object has the name and the address of a user, and I need to get those. How would I do that?

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "People")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if(error == nil){
            for object in objects!{

                self.peopleObj.append(object)



            }


        }else{
            print(error)
        }
}
```

Would I do something like `peopleObj["Name"]`, I don't think that is the correct syntax for a PFObject.

Comment: what is the use of that "self.peopleObj"? are append the whole object?

Comment: peopleObj is a [PFObject]

Comment: why you appending whole object?

Comment: I need to access it in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a loop to access the single object and then fetch value like below:

```
for Oneobject in objects
{
   let strAddress = Oneobject["address"] as String
   let strName = Oneobject["name"] as String
}
```

Refer the following link:
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects